# Rails 3.1 can't mass assign protected attributes for non database model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The part of rails 3.1 that handles `attr_accessor` is apparently broken.

I have several models that do not have a database at all and some that have attributes that are not persisted.

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #persisted attribs
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :is_admin, :permissions

  #non persisted attribs<br />
  attr_accessor :roseburg, :kfc, :kcpl
  ........
```

if I attempt to save the the user in the controllers create or update with

```
def create<br />
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
```

or

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

I get a error something like `Cannot mass assign protected attributes :roseburg, :kfc, 
:kcpl`

The workaround is to populate the attributes and use the save method.

```
def create
  @user = User.new             

  (params[:user]).each do |attr_name, attr_value| 
    if @user.respond_to?("#{attr_name}")
      @user.send("#{attr_name}=", attr_value)                  
    end
  end

  @user.save
    .....
```

and

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|

  (params[:user]).each do |attr_name, attr_value| 
    if @user.respond_to?("#{attr_name}")
      @user.send("#{attr_name}=", attr_value)                  
    end    
  end

  if @user.save
  ....
```

my question is what effect does this have on security?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a hash to a method like `new`, `create`, or `update_attributes`, Rails will make sure that you can only mass-assign attributes that are allowed with `attr_accessible` (or, alternatively, will not allow attributes blacklisted with `attr_protected`).

If you don't add `:roseburg`, `:kfc`, and `:kcpl` to `attr_accessible`, it will throw a mass-assignment error like the one that you describe.

Having them defined by `attr_accessor` only guarantees that you'll have setters and getters (e.g., `roseburg=` and `roseburg`), which has nothing to do with Rails's mass-assignment checks. `attr_accessor` is actually a Ruby construct, not anything provided by ActiveRecord.

If you don't add the non-persisted attributes to `attr_accessible`, you'll need to manually assign the values when initializing your model instance like you describe in your question.

Comment: If I add them to attr_accessible, Rails tries to save them to the database and gives me  ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#update

Comment: If I add them to attr_accessible, Rails tries to save them to the database and gives me  
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#update

But (discovery here) when I add them to both lists... it works fine with default new(params[user]) and update.
Go figure.

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :is_admin, :permissions, :roseburg, :kfc, :kcpl
  
  attr_accessor :roseburg, :kfc, :kcpl

That was not expected, at least by me or any other thread I have searched